# Understanding mean curvature and Weingarten maps

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

The parametrized surface:
$$\textbf{R}\supset{U}\ni(x,y)\longmapsto (x,y,f(x,y))\in\textbf{R}^3$$
defined by the graph of a smooth function $z=f(x,y)$ 
I know that the Weingarten map:$$L:=II\circ I^{-1}$$ equals the Guassian curvature.
Now I'm interested in calculating that the trace of L (which I believe is the mean curvature of this surface) and using that to prove that the surface has mean curvature zero if and only if $f$ satisfies the minimal surface equation, namely $$H=\frac{(1+h_y^2)h_{xx}-2h_xh_yh_{xy}+(1+h_x^2)h_{yy}}{2(1+h_x^2+h_y^2)^{3/2}}$$

Comment: First of all, you should have $L=I^{-1}II$. Secondly, the Gaussian curvature is the determinant of this map. Yes, up to a factor of $1/2$, you do want the trace. You seem to have some confusion, moreover, with $f$ versus $h$. So given your parametrization, compute $I$ and $II$ and do it!

Comment: but isn't this a trivial excersize with $(x,y,f(x,y))$? Is it not just the generic form of the first and second fundamental form?

Comment: If it's so "trivial," why did you ask? It is not a difficult exercise (except for your scrambling letters and messing up the order of the matrix multiplication).

Comment: @TedShifrin sorry I didn't mean to provoke anything. Indeed, the difference between $f$ and $h$ are confusing to me, would you mind parsing that out?

Comment: All those $h$'s should be $f$'s !!